# My strcpy_s won't work with my char *pointer, why?

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

Ok, so I am trying to fix my C++ assignment, but when I use strcpy_s it only works for my array and not my *pointer.. here is what I am working with:

```
HotelRoom::HotelRoom(char Num[], int cap, double daily, char* name, int Stat)
{
strcpy_s(room_Num, Num); //copy first argument into room_Num[]
guest = new char[strlen(name) +1]; //create space for the name
strcpy_s(guest, name); //copy second argument into new space
capacity = cap;
dailyRate = daily;
occupancyStat = Stat;
}
```

This is the error I get when using it in this manner strcpy_s(guest, name); :

"no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches the argument list argument types are: (char*, char*)".﻿

Comment: Probably a useless question, but why don't you use a string?

Comment: different function signature? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Nil, becasue the book assignment says to use a char* and a Char[]

Comment: @kenny, I read that site before posting here; and I don't understand what it is saying. That is why I am posting here. I am a beginner.

Comment: @SyntaxEyes look at the answer from Yu below. It has different arguments or signature of the standard strcpy() or yore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-standard `strcpy_s` takes one extra parameter than `std::strcpy` that is the max size you want to copy.

```
errno_t strcpy_s(char *s1, size_t s1max, const char *s2);
```

What you need is the standard C function `std::strcpy`.

```
char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Comment: when I use:

char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);

it output a bunch of symbols like "==^&%$@".

But when I use:

Comment: but when I use:

strcpy_s(char *s1, size_t s1max, const char *s2);

it works, but at end of compiling it errors with a "break" error, or something like that.

Comment: @SyntaxEyes C-style strings need to be null-terminated, make sure of that. Or better, use `std::string` if that's an option.

Comment: @YuHao, FYI `strcpy_s` is a standard C11 function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy.

Comment: @Annie And this is a C++ question.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

When the size cannot be determined automatically because a statically sized array is not being passed you must provide it.

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char src[] = "Hello World!\n";
    char staticDest[100];
    size_t dynamicSize = strlen(src) + 1;
    char* dynamicDest = new char[dynamicSize];

    //Use the overload that can determine the size automatically
    //because the array size is fixed
    //template <size_t size> errno_t strcpy_s(char(&strDestination)[size], const char *strSource);
    strcpy_s(staticDest, src);

    //Use the overload that requires an additional size parameter because
    //the memory is dynamically allocated
    //errno_t strcpy_s(char *strDestination, size_t numberOfElements, const char *strSource);
    strcpy_s(dynamicDest, dynamicSize, src);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't that what I am doing here:

guest = new char[strlen(name) +1];

doesn't that make room for the pointer to hold name?

Comment: No, since you are dynamically allocating the memory you have to tell the function how large the destination buffer is.  If you have a static array like `char s[100];` the templated overload can automatically determine the size.  I added an example of both in the answer.

Comment: OOHHH! I see. Ok so I used your second example with the 3 arguments, and now after compile is complete it pops up with a error that says "breakpoint" then it says abort when I click "break" button.

Comment: You should be able to see in the debugger the line where the error occurred.  Without seeing all of your code it's hard to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: In both of these calls to `strcpy_s` the code should check the returned value. Otherwise, it offers only a small advantage over simply calling `strcpy`: it replaces a buffer overrun with data corruption.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a demonstration of the two different versions of it.  In real code checking for errors is important.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
strcpy_s(guest, strlen(name), name); //copy second argument into new space
```

Comment: would have to be strcpy_s(guest, strlen(name)+1, name) and works around the warning and around the intention why strcpy_s was introduced anyhow.